How to send different images with different captions telegram bot
So I'm trying to make a telegram bot that can send images with captions underneath, but i want every that every photo has a different caption. I've been trying for a long time and this is what i have right now :
import requests
import time

base_url = "https://api.telegram.org/botnotgoingtodisplayforsafety/sendPhoto"

urls = [
        "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/ASHH5bDmsp6wnK6mEfZdcU.jpg",
        "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/small-fluffy-dog-breeds-maltipoo-66300ad363389.jpg?crop=0.668xw:1.00xh;0.151xw,0&resize=640:*",
        "https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_fit-760w,f_auto,q_auto:best/streams/2013/May/130522/6C7536084-g-hlt-120105-puppy-423p.jpg"
        
]

caps = ["1", "2", "3"
        
]

for url in urls:
  
  time.sleep(1)  
  parameters = {
      "chat_id" : "-notgoingtodisplayforsafety",
      "photo" : url,
      "caption" : caps
  }

  resp = requests.get(base_url, data = parameters)
  print(resp.text)


So what the problem is now that it sends every image from the 'urls' list but it doesn't use the 'caps' list. So it send the first image with caption : 1, then the second image with caption : 1 again and to forth. Does anyone now how i should be doing this and what im doing wrong?
I was trying to make a telegram bot that can send different images with different captions underneath.

An image can only contain a single cap, and if you send it as a group, the same applies. Just send 3 seperate images with captions.

I think it's more of a your python source issue. You're only looping through the urls. If you want to consider two lists at the same time use another logic, here's one with the zip method.
for url, caption in zip(urls, caps):
    time.sleep(1)
    parameters = {
        "chat_id": "-notgoingtodisplayforsafety",
        "photo": url,
        "caption": caption
    }

    resp = requests.get(base_url, data=parameters)
    print(resp.text)

Or you can use the good old, for i in range syntax:
for i in range(len(urls)):
    time.sleep(1)
    parameters = {
        "chat_id": "-notgoingtodisplayforsafety",
        "photo": urls[i],
        "caption": caps[i]
    }

    resp = requests.get(base_url, data=parameters)
    print(resp.text)

Hope this helps :)
